# Multi patch to Collada - 3D Buildings

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene, multipatch, collada

I have extruded building footprints using the height of each building in ArcScene. I have converted them into multi patch using Layer 3D to Feature Class and now i want to apply textures on those buildings in Sketchup. I must first convert the multi patch into collada format but when i use the tool, it doesn't work and is giving me kml even though the tool didnt work. The  result is attached below:
[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You say "when i use the tool, it doesn't work" but what are the precise parameters and any error messages when you try running that tool?

Comment: Ive edited and included the snapshot

Comment: Please provide a text description of the tool parameters used and any errors. Pictures are not searchable and may not be renderable on all sites and from all workplaces.

Comment: Can i give you the data please?

Comment: No - SE sites are not designed for individual help. They are intended for building a Q&A repository for future searches to find instant answers so we need any data and workflows to be described in detail as part of your question.

Comment: The tool parameters are- Input: Collada Data and output is the directory where it was stored. Use field name i left it as FID

Comment: The error message us attached above on the question

Comment: Please take the [Tour] to learn about the site and its protocols. There is an [edit] button beneath your question that you should use to provide any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

The tool is working properly for me.  You could try to use it within ModelBuilder or with ArcPy.  Otherwise, you can still import the kml in Sketchup, apply the textures and export it to a kmz. I found it is easier to import a kmz in a geodatabase as a multipatch (using the tool kml to layer).

Comment: I dont know how to use model builder, i'm not well versed with ArcMap. So what youre saying is export it as  kml from Arc, apply the photos in sketch up and then import in back to arc?

Comment: Well, the good thing with a kmz is that is it georeferenced and a can be imported in SketchUp. So you can export a kmz using Layer To KML tool, then in SketchUp Import the kmz, do your work in it, save it (it will be a .skp file) and finally export it to a kmz. You can import a kmz by using KML To Layer tool. It will create a multipatch in a geodatabase. You will need to convert to multipatch using Layer 3D to feature Class.